# Unable to start IntelliJ Ultimate

Tags: windows, intellij-idea

When launching Intellij Ultimate

```
Internal error. Please refer to http://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors

java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:461)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:453)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:227)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:132)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:551)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1345)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:503)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:488)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:984)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:247)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:355)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:416)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:515)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:918)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

-----
JRE 11.0.4+10-b304.77 amd64 by JetBrains s.r.o
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\192.7142.36\jbr
```

Already tried removing the plugins folder but still getting the same error.

Comment: You'll get the `Address already in use` error when there is an application running on the same port. You will want to find this hanging process and terminate it. This is one of those cases where the old adage `restart your computer` actually rings true.

Answer (score 1):

To lock folders IDE is starting a server on localhost, it tries to bind on the first available port between 6942 and 6991, this exception is thrown if IDE was not able to bind on any of the ports in this range. All 50 ports are unlikely to be already used on a machine, so it appears to be a networking issue or some security software which doesn't permit IDE to bind on any port in this range even on localhost interface.

You can check with TcpView if these ports are already taken: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview . It will show the process using the ports.

But in case of the firewall it can just block the bind operation and TcpView will not show anything.

Reboot or fixing the network should help. You can also try `netsh winsock reset`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the *BindException* on Windows multiple times.

At some point, I found that switching from my docking station using Ethernet to WiFi and back is sometimes causing this issue. To solve it, I use PowerShell to restart the network adapter. For some reason, I either need to restart the WiFi or the Ethernet adapter. To stop guessing, I just restart all of them in a loop. Note that running transfers might be interrupted.

Start PowerShell as an **Administrator**. Then type:

```
Get-NetAdapter | Restart-NetAdapter
```

To restart an individual adapter, use *Get-NetAdapter* to find its name, then type:

```
Restart-NetAdapter 'name'
```